# Using Google MAP API, how can I have multiple colors for different map.data.addGeoJson() calls?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

With one route, I could do

```
  map.data.addGeoJson(self.opts.geojson);
  map.data.setStyle({strokeColor: self.opts.geojson_stroke_color || "#3b5aa8"});
```

But with multiple calls to addGeoJson() map.data.setStyle only applies once
I tried:

```
let colors = ['#fcba03', '#035afc', '#03fc56'];
for(let i = 0; i < self.opts.geojson_array.length; ++i){
   try {
      map.data.addGeoJson(self.opts.geojson_array[i]);
      map.data.setStyle({ strokeColor: colors[i%colors.length] || self.opts.geojson_stroke_color || "#3b5aa8" });
  }catch(error){
      this.error = error;
      console.log(error);
  }
}
```

But they all end up as one and the same color.

How do I get different colors for each route (geojson wtih addGeoJson() call)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to create a separate [`Data`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data) object for each set of GeoJSON data.

```
  let colors = ['#fcba03', '#035afc', '#03fc56'];
  for (let i = 0; i < self.opts.geojson_array.length; ++i) {
    try {
      let layer = new google.maps.Data();
      layer.setMap(map);
      layer.addGeoJson(self.opts.geojson_array[i]);
      layer.setStyle({
        strokeColor: colors[i % colors.length] || self.opts.geojson_stroke_color || "#3b5aa8"
      });
    } catch (error) {
      this.error = error;
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/p9qLyad6/1/)

[image: screenshot of map with different styles]

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: -28,
      lng: 137
    },
  });

  let colors = ['#fcba03', '#035afc', '#03fc56'];
  for (let i = 0; i < geojson_array.length; ++i) {
    try {
      let layer = new google.maps.Data();
      layer.setMap(map);
      layer.addGeoJson(geojson_array[i]);
      layer.setStyle({
        strokeColor: colors[i % colors.length] || self.opts.geojson_stroke_color || "#3b5aa8"
      });
    } catch (error) {
      error = error;
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}

window.initMap = initMap;

let geojson_array = [{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "letter": "G",
        "color": "blue",
        "rank": "7",
        "ascii": "71"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [123.61, -22.14],
            [122.38, -21.73],
            [121.06, -21.69],
            [119.66, -22.22],
            [119.00, -23.40],
            [118.65, -24.76],
            [118.43, -26.07],
            [118.78, -27.56],
            [119.22, -28.57],
            [120.23, -29.49],
            [121.77, -29.87],
            [123.57, -29.64],
            [124.45, -29.03],
            [124.71, -27.95],
            [124.80, -26.70],
            [124.80, -25.60],
            [123.61, -25.64],
            [122.56, -25.64],
            [121.72, -25.72],
            [121.81, -26.62],
            [121.86, -26.98],
            [122.60, -26.90],
            [123.57, -27.05],
            [123.57, -27.68],
            [123.35, -28.18],
            [122.51, -28.38],
            [121.77, -28.26],
            [121.02, -27.91],
            [120.49, -27.21],
            [120.14, -26.50],
            [120.10, -25.64],
            [120.27, -24.52],
            [120.67, -23.68],
            [121.72, -23.32],
            [122.43, -23.48],
            [123.04, -24.04],
            [124.54, -24.28],
            [124.58, -23.20],
            [123.61, -22.14]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }, ]
  },
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [

      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "letter": "o",
          "color": "red",
          "rank": "15",
          "ascii": "111"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [128.84, -25.76],
              [128.18, -25.60],
              [127.96, -25.52],
              [127.88, -25.52],
              [127.70, -25.60],
              [127.26, -25.79],
              [126.60, -26.11],
              [126.16, -26.78],
              [126.12, -27.68],
              [126.21, -28.42],
              [126.69, -29.49],
              [127.74, -29.80],
              [128.80, -29.72],
              [129.41, -29.03],
              [129.72, -27.95],
              [129.68, -27.21],
              [129.33, -26.23],
              [128.84, -25.76]
            ],
            [
              [128.45, -27.44],
              [128.32, -26.94],
              [127.70, -26.82],
              [127.35, -27.05],
              [127.17, -27.80],
              [127.57, -28.22],
              [128.10, -28.42],
              [128.49, -27.80],
              [128.45, -27.44]
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [

      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "letter": "o",
          "color": "yellow",
          "rank": "15",
          "ascii": "111"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [131.87, -25.76],
              [131.35, -26.07],
              [130.95, -26.78],
              [130.82, -27.64],
              [130.86, -28.53],
              [131.26, -29.22],
              [131.92, -29.76],
              [132.45, -29.87],
              [133.06, -29.76],
              [133.72, -29.34],
              [134.07, -28.80],
              [134.20, -27.91],
              [134.07, -27.21],
              [133.81, -26.31],
              [133.37, -25.83],
              [132.71, -25.64],
              [131.87, -25.76]
            ],
            [
              [133.15, -27.17],
              [132.71, -26.86],
              [132.09, -26.90],
              [131.74, -27.56],
              [131.79, -28.26],
              [132.36, -28.45],
              [132.93, -28.34],
              [133.15, -27.76],
              [133.15, -27.17]
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [

      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "letter": "g",
          "color": "blue",
          "rank": "7",
          "ascii": "103"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [138.12, -25.04],
              [136.84, -25.16],
              [135.96, -25.36],
              [135.26, -25.99],
              [135, -26.90],
              [135.04, -27.91],
              [135.26, -28.88],
              [136.05, -29.45],
              [137.02, -29.49],
              [137.81, -29.49],
              [137.94, -29.99],
              [137.90, -31.20],
              [137.85, -32.24],
              [136.88, -32.69],
              [136.45, -32.36],
              [136.27, -31.80],
              [134.95, -31.84],
              [135.17, -32.99],
              [135.52, -33.43],
              [136.14, -33.76],
              [137.06, -33.83],
              [138.12, -33.65],
              [138.86, -33.21],
              [139.30, -32.28],
              [139.30, -31.24],
              [139.30, -30.14],
              [139.21, -28.96],
              [139.17, -28.22],
              [139.08, -27.41],
              [139.08, -26.47],
              [138.99, -25.40],
              [138.73, -25.00],
              [138.12, -25.04]
            ],
            [
              [137.50, -26.54],
              [136.97, -26.47],
              [136.49, -26.58],
              [136.31, -27.13],
              [136.31, -27.72],
              [136.58, -27.99],
              [137.50, -28.03],
              [137.68, -27.68],
              [137.59, -26.78],
              [137.50, -26.54]
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [

      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "letter": "l",
          "color": "green",
          "rank": "12",
          "ascii": "108"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [140.14, -21.04],
              [140.31, -29.42],
              [141.67, -29.49],
              [141.59, -20.92],
              [140.14, -21.04]
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [

      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "letter": "e",
          "color": "red",
          "rank": "5",
          "ascii": "101"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [144.14, -27.41],
              [145.67, -27.52],
              [146.86, -27.09],
              [146.82, -25.64],
              [146.25, -25.04],
              [145.45, -24.68],
              [144.66, -24.60],
              [144.09, -24.76],
              [143.43, -25.08],
              [142.99, -25.40],
              [142.64, -26.03],
              [142.64, -27.05],
              [142.64, -28.26],
              [143.30, -29.11],
              [144.18, -29.57],
              [145.41, -29.64],
              [146.46, -29.19],
              [146.64, -28.72],
              [146.82, -28.14],
              [144.84, -28.42],
              [144.31, -28.26],
              [144.14, -27.41]
            ],
            [
              [144.18, -26.39],
              [144.53, -26.58],
              [145.19, -26.62],
              [145.72, -26.35],
              [145.81, -25.91],
              [145.41, -25.68],
              [144.97, -25.68],
              [144.49, -25.64],
              [144, -25.99],
              [144.18, -26.39]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

```css
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Data Layer: Dynamic Styling</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- 
     The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
     document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
     and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises
     with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader.
    -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```